# varied htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I'm trying to get SEO sorted for my website but I can't seem to figure out this scenario.

I want to have 4 query parameters, `$cat`, `$subcat`, `$page`, `$othervars`

but I need a htaccess rule to allow these values:

1. domain.com/cat/page
2. domain.com/cat/subcat/page
3. domain.com/cat
4. domain.com/cat/subcat/page/other

How can I achieve this, so far all I have is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /beta/index.php?cat=$1&cat2=$2&page=$3&var=$4 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /beta/index.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /beta/index.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /beta/index.php?cat=$1&cat2=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /beta/index.php?cat=$1&cat2=$2&page=$3&var=$4 [L]
```

Comment: @ChristopherBrix it isn't the same, you posted redirects, Hampus posted actually rewrite rules. Hampus it all seems to be working just how I want it to be :) thanks a bundle!

Comment: @ChristopherBrix yeah, sorry. Almost the same at least - I would give you the points if I could...

Answer (score 1):

Do the parsing in PHP instead!

.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /beta/index.php?var=$1 [L]
```

... and in index.php

```
$vars = explode("/",$_GET['var']);
$cat = isset($vars[0]) ? $vars[0] : false;
$subcat = isset($vars[1]) ? $vars[1] : false;
$page = isset($vars[2]) ? $vars[2] : false;
$othervars = isset($vars[3]) ? $vars[3] : false;
```

Comment: Thanks, this could be one way around it, I'll leave the question open in case anyone has another way around this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to these use 4 RewriteRules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /beta/index.php?cat=$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /beta/index.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /beta/index.php?cat=$1&cat2=$2&page=$3 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /beta/index.php?cat=$1&cat2=$2&page=$3&var=$4 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Sorry but that's not working, it's redirecting instead of rewriting.